# How to do not let Thread stop themeselves when in standby mode?

Tags: android, multithreading, background

In my application i have a service created in a different thread than the main one (UI).
Then, in the service, i created 3 others threads that execute in background indefinitely.
But as soon as the phone goes in standby mode, these threads suspend their execution!

If i connect the phone to the pc via usb cable, instead, i see that the threads work properly, without suspending themeselves even when in standby mode.

But how to do not let threads have this behaviour in normal execution?

tnx

SOLVED:

I managed to get this simply by using the PowerManager object, which acquire a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK that leave the cpu active from the acquire() to the release().

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
 PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
 wl.acquire();
   ..CPU will stay on during this section..
 wl.release();
```

Comment: Doesn't standby mode involve putting the CPU to sleep?  If so, it's hard to see how you could have any threads executing while in standby mode, since allowing a thread to execute would mean waking up the CPU again, at which point you wouldn't be in standby mode anymore.

Comment: Hi, tnx your words make me understand how to solve the problem! :D (edited the question with solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get this simply by using the PowerManager object, which acquire a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK that leave the cpu active from the acquire() invocation till the release() invocation.

In this way even if phone goes in stanbdy mode, thread is sure to be running.

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
 PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
 wl.acquire();
   ..CPU will stay on during this section..
 wl.release();
```